# SAPUI5 BTP Cloud Foundry How to create SAPUI5 News in CF Launchpad?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-cloud-foundry, sap-business-technology-platform

I'm trying to migrate SAP BTP Neo Cloud Portal apps to SAP BTP Cloud Foundry. Im facing an issue in migrating an application which I configured **App type as News in SAP BTP Neo**.

Below is the pic of **SAP BTP Neo** Cloud Portal. Here we have an option to configure the **App Type** as **SAPUI5 News**:

[image: Screenshot SAP BTP Neo selecting SAPUI5 News]

Below is the pic in **SAP BTP Cloud Foundry**. Here we **don't have an option to configure our app type as SAPUI5 News**:

[image: Screenshot SAP BTP CF no SAPUI5 News]

Can someone please help me to configure below apps in SAP BTP Cloud Foundry portal, which can be done in SAP BTP Neo by configuring the App Type as SAPUI5 News?

[image: SAPUI5 News tile sample screenshot]